# How can I replace the last character of a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 11...

I have a "person" table that has these 4 boolean fields:

```
person
---------
user
employee
supplier
customer
```

Now I want to return in a query a text formated with the rules of a person in the system. For example:

If the person is just a customer, return 'customer';

If is supplier and customer, return 'supplier and customer';

If is employee, supplier and customer: 'employee, supplier and customer'

First I check the columns and return the corresponding text using CASE. Then I used the "concat_ws" function to bring only what is of value, looking like this:

```
SELECT
    concat_ws(', ',
        CASE WHEN user THEN 'user' END,
        CASE WHEN employee THEN 'employee' END,
        CASE WHEN supplier THEN 'supplier' END,
        CASE WHEN customer THEN 'customer' END
    ) AS rules
FROM
    person
```

Result:
'customer'
'supplier, customer'
employee, supplier, customer '

With that I almost got to the result, but I need to concatenate "and" at the end when there is more than one value.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve or a more friendly way?

Comment: Are other combinations possible, for example *employer and customer*, or *user and supplier*?

Comment: @GMB Yes! There are even 3 more rules, being possible to have several combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to wrap the expression in `regexp_replace()`

```
regexp_replace(
    concat_ws(', ',
        CASE WHEN user THEN 'user' END,
        CASE WHEN employee THEN 'employee' END,
        CASE WHEN supplier THEN 'supplier' END,
        CASE WHEN customer THEN 'customer' END
    ),
    ', (\w+)$',
    'and \1'
)
```

The regex searches for the last sequence of a comma followed by a variable number of word characters (and captures it) and replaces it with *and* followed by the captured word.

Comment: Almost that! Created the "and" in the last concatenation but also brought a comma in the last value: employee, supplier and , customer

Comment: @Renato: yes I was just fixing this... Thanks.